# NodeJS - Make HTTPS GET request

Tags: node.js

I'm not able to execute an HTTPS request from my NodeJS webserver to a public service.

Here the code:

```
const https = require('https');

        var httpOptions = {
            hostname: <URL>,
            path: <PATH>,
            port:443,
            method:"GET",
            auth: <USERNAME>+":"+<PASSWORD>
        }
        console.log(httpOptions);    

        https.get(httpOptions,(res)=>{
            console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);

            res.on('data', function (chunk) {
                console.log("DATA");
            });

            res.on('end',(error)=>{
                console.log("END");
            });

            res.on('error',(error)=>{
                console.log("ERRROR");
            });

        });
```

I get as response this:

```
Error: Hostname/IP doesn't match certificate's altnames: "Host: https. is not in the cert's altnames: DNS:*.ng.bluemix.net, DNS:ng.bluemix.net"
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: So what IS the "Hostname"?

Comment: I checked the hostname value and I found the error. I have included the "https://<HOSTNAME>" at the beginning of the value. After removed it, everything worked well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the wrong hostname.
I removed the protocol at the beginning:

```
"https://example.com" => "example.com"
```

After that it worked well.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the URL you are using does not have a valid SSL cert.